# Sending data gives [object HTMLInputElement] as query response

Tags: html, ajax, forms, api

I am trying to send user form data to partner endpoint like this:

```
$('#registrationFrm').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "https://pixel.plexop.com/?country="+countryid+"&_v=6&name="+firstName+"&lastname="+lastName+"&phone="+phone
+"&email="+emailid+"&ud=&e=2&adv=1&a=4&f=221161&FormId=1807&SerialId=1210053",
data: $("#registrationFrm").serialize(),
success: function() {
alert('success');
 }
});
});
```

I get 200 "OK" back, but as of data I get this sent when I inspect it on "network":

```
Query string: country   "[object HTMLSelectElement]
Query string: name  "[object HTMLInputElement]
Query string: lastname  "[object HTMLInputElement]"
```

My form looks like this:

```
<form id="registrationFrm" >
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" id="firstName" required />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" id="lastName" required />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone No" name="phone" id="phone" required />
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone form-control-feedback"></span>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example? It would help to see all of the `var` declarations for `countryid`, `firstName`, `lastName`, `phone`, and `emailid`, along with the relevant HTML of the form fields.

Comment: So you're sending the data in the URL and the request body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you define your variables like:

```
const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
/*and so*/
```

But you should do this like:

```
const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
```

**UPD:**

```
$('#registrationFrm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:
            'https://pixel.plexop.com/?country=' +
            countryid.value +
            '&_v=6&name=' +
            firstName.value +
            '&lastname=' +
            lastName.value +
            '&phone=' +
            phone.value +
            '&email=' +
            emailid.value +
            '&ud=&e=2&adv=1&a=4&f=221161&FormId=1807&SerialId=1210053',
        data: $('#registrationFrm').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't added any const to it at all. Should this be implemented in the index.html?

Comment: You'd better do that, but you can do this: *check my answer again*